# If a new nation on an artificial island was founded, what kinds of names might it be given?

Tags: politics, names

In my story, an artificial island nation is built. I need to give it a name!

If somebody were to build a new nation, how would it be named, and what kinds of names might it get? I'm *not* interested in a list of names - rather, I want ideas about the process that would be used to select a name, and what *types* of names would potentially be selected.

---

Some more details:

This story takes place in a nearly utopian liberal political environment. A federation that is culturally similar to Europe that has a lot of say over what happens in a region approximately a quarter of a hemisphere of the planet in size.

This setting is somewhat post-scarcity - there are still socioeconomic classes, but the lowest classes are similar to the lower-middle class in modern America and each nation can easily afford a very generous welfare program that catches virtually everyone who falls into true poverty. Overall, most nations have a government that is a semi-utopian ideal of how modern democracy should work.

One of the challenges facing this federation is that every country within it is close to overpopulated. Since the federation has an abundance of resources but is continually running out of land for people to live, it has a major program of building artificial islands large enough to become small countries. (The islands are sky islands. This is practical because Magic, and it also allows the islands to be built three-dimensionally, making them have a smaller two-dimensional footprint on a map.) Since the islands are artificial, they don't have a lot of natural resources, so most people who live in them either have white-collar jobs or work in construction, providing maintenance for the islands.

There are a few other federations like this around the world. They have different cultures, but are also somewhat utopian in their own ways, and all of the federations have good relationships with each other. Most people are accepting of people of other races.

If this setting sounds too good to be true, that's what I'm aiming for. The conflict comes from a Lovecraftian force threatening to destroy the stability of this political system.

My story focuses on one particular island that starts its nationhood about halfway through the process of being completed. Other nations and the system of federations don't appear much outside of the backstory. But I think that information is relevant for describing why I want to name an artificial island and helps provide some context for how that island might be named.

Comment: The European Union can not found a new nation. This is not how sovereign entities appear.

Comment: @AlexP I am aware. I'm asking to get ideas for my fictional story, not to get information about the actual European Union.

Comment: New sovereign entities appear when a _previously existing entity_ is recognized as a sovereign by other sovereigns. Your sovereign artificial nation will simply continue to use the name of the island as it was before being recognized as sovereign. Are you asking for names of imaginary islands? If that is the case just say so, and indicate whether you want the name to be English-like or Romance-like or Slavic-like or sort-of-classical-Greco-Latin-like.

Comment: @AlexP I added some more details about my specific setting. I believe that in my story, having a federation build new sovereign nations is justified. It might function a bit more like the United States chartering a new state than a new nation appearing, though.

Comment: The kingdom of Bob. Short and sure to strike fear into the hearts of even the most viscous dictators.

Comment: "not to get information about the actual [EU]" Well, then remove the reference to the actual EU. Because the EU is really in no position to do anything of the like - each member state could recognize that new state or could refuse to do so on their own. The EU is really loose, it's more like a catalogue of treaties which states ratify and they can even pick and choose to a degree.

Comment: I'm reminded of *Against A Dark Background*, which has a throwaway line about the region 'Regionner' with capital 'Capitaller', given placeholder names after centuries of incomprehensible legal disputes.

Comment: This question has an exemplary amount of context.

Comment: Utopian.  European Union.  Utopian.  Zero economic growth for 20 years (Spain), a decade of imposed austerity (and more to come!) to "repay" debts that will never be repaid (Greece), a decade of recession in a productive modern economy due to no control over monetary policy (Finland, Euro), maritime environmental catastrophe (common fisheries policy), free-trade is ruled illegal (Common Market)....  "Utopian".  Hmm.  Starting concept is too ridiculous to even answer!!  : )

Comment: Some examples: [Republic of Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Rose_Island), 
[Principality of Sealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Sealand), 
[REM Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REM_Island)

Comment: There are some examples of nations that are quite recent in Europe. For example Kosovo took the name of the Kosovo plains (an actual location), Macedonia took the name of the ancient kingdom of Alexander The Great (Macedon, much to the Greeks dislike), Spain is named after the ancient Roman name for the Iberian Peninsula -Hispania (whose origin is likely Phoenician). The same with Great Britain since "just" Britain (Bretagne) is in the north of France (also: New Zealand is "New" because Zealand is in the Netherlands).

Comment: "If an entity like the modern European Union were to found a new nation" The premise is flawed. They can't they have no basis for that. The EU is a union of sovereign nations, but they have no authority whatsoever to "found" a new nation.

Comment: @Nobody Good point, I removed the reference to the EU.

Comment: Why not let the people (or founder) name the nation? What name (any why) would they choose?

Comment: If they ask the Internet to vote, it might end up Islandy McIslandface. https://www.nytimes.com/2016/03/22/world/europe/boaty-mcboatface-what-you-get-when-you-let-the-internet-decide.html

Comment: @Close voters why are you voting to close? As I specifically discussed in my question, I'm not asking for band suggestions, but rather for ideas on the process for which a name might be selected.

Comment: Wouldn't happen in the real world.  One of the assorted maritime treaties (I think it's the [Convention on the Law of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Convention_on_the_Law_of_the_Sea)) states that artificial islands cannot be sovereign territory in their own right.  This was intended to keep countries from expanding their territorial waters, but it has the side effect of preventing new island nations from being built.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

New places are often named for:

1. People influential in founding them (e.g. Louisiana, Virginia).
2. People who paid for them (e.g. Carnegie Library, Sports Authority Field, the Guggenheim Museum, Ford Motor Company).
3. Historical figures we are proud of (e.g. Washington, Lincoln, Seneca).
4. Distinctive physical features of the place, not necessarily true (e.g. Greenland, Iceland, Colorado).
5. Places the settlers migrated from or wanted to associate themselves with (e.g. New Guinea, New York, New Mexico, Oxford, Cambridge, New Caledonia, Athens, Rome, the Amazon - the original is in the Pontic-Caspian steppe).
6. Legendary places (e.g. Gilead, Jerusalem, Hades, Olympus).
7. Virtues and ideals (e.g. Utopia, Tranquility, Serenity, Friendship, Union).
8. Previous residents (e.g. Miami, Arapahoe, Pueblo, the Dakotas).
9. Things produced or acquired in trade at a place (e.g. Leadville, Iron Mountain, Britain means "Tin Land" in Punic, and Ireland means "Copper Land").
10. Historical events (e.g. Centennial for a city in a state formed on the one hundredth anniversary of the founding of the nation).
11. Neighboring territories (e.g. West Virginia, South Sudan).
12. A general geographical location (e.g. South Africa, Central African Republic, Copper River, East Timor, South China Sea, Dotsoro - i.e. a point at the intersection of zero latitude and longitude on a map grid).

Comment: These are exactly the kinds of ideas I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Brasilia, the artificially created capital city of Brasil.

Comment: Nice list. So a future naming after current EU leaders could include: JunkerBurg, Draghistan and Tuskany. 
Naming places are fun :-)

Comment: The Cambridge and Oxford in the UK were named for the bridge over the river Cam, and a ford that Oxen were driven over. We're an inventive bunch.

Comment: As far as I understand it, Greenland is called Greenland because the person who found it called it Greenland to attract people to it. As such, you can list another reason to name a place - propaganda.

Comment: @Abulafia wouldn't Junkerburg be a city?

Comment: Wait, is Jerusalem (in the middle east) named after a legendary place, or do you just mean all the other Jerusalems that are named after it? If the second, doesn't that fit better in 5.? and for that matter, shouldn't the Amazon be in 6?

Comment: For added fun, add in other languages: even something mundane like "Hill  Town" can sound much more "romantic" if you use a foreign language.  By this, I mean a language that is (no longer) dominant in that region - not necessarily a dead language.  The U.S. is full of place-names in French, Spanish, and various native tongues.

Answer (score 9):

If there was a new nation in the area of the EU, it would be carved out of the area of an existing country. For an island it would be out of the [exclusive economic zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_economic_zone) of a country.

**The place has a name**.

If the island were raised in the [Dogger Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogger_Bank), it might become [Doggerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doggerland) again.

An island in the intertidal zone might be called after geographic features in the area, like the [IJsseloog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJsseloog).

For a purely fictional name, Greek mythology might be a source of the EU bureaucrats get their choice, or the company name of a sponsor ...

Comment: Oh no... can you imagine how sponsorship would turn out? Red Bull Island? Allianz-land? Bet365 Land?

Comment: The Flevopolder in IJsseloog being a good example. It's a new "polder" named after lake Flevo or Flevoland itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flevopolder

Comment: +1 for greek mythology - old enough and respected enough to be accepted by all members without them feeling that one member is being preferred (i.e. jealous that Greece is being chosen as the special culture).

Answer (score 4):

> If an entity like the modern European Union were to found a new nation, how would it be named, and what kinds of names might it get?

It's hard to imagine entities like the European Union to found a new nation, because it would rather want to integrate than to split up but I guess if they wanted to it would rather choose a **bureaucratic** approach maybe with an acronym.

Something like:

- SAZ5 (Self Administrated Zone Number 5)
- FES (Free European Sector)
- EAR-W (European Autonomous Region Wallony)

Answer (score 4):

In my story 35 years ago, I named it Altus, because it means “tall” or something like that.  It’s named after the physical attribute, because it’s an inverse hi-rise, building downward starting from a floating platform.

All the place names of settlements were given names evocotive of the location.

Consider the way the specific founders think: who were they? What were their motivations when building the place? Do they have a dead leader they revere?  What language are they speaking?  Are there any culturally significant stories that they might draw upon?

Answer (score 1):

Europa seems like a safe bet. It perhaps could act as a neutral federal district for the EU

Comment: There would be a lot of satirical mileage in this plot: EU builds artificial island on mid-Atlantic ridge, relocates government from Brussels and Strasburg as some sort of symbolic act, maybe fostering transatlantic harmony. One night during a great storm, it sinks.

Answer (score 1):

- Greek-ish names starting with *Eu*:

  Eudamena (storm-stiller), Eudiaereta (easily separated),
  Eudiatheta (well  placed), Euglossia (sweet-voiced),
  Euergetema (kindness), Euergeta (benefactrix), Euphamia (praise),
  Euphantasmia (imaginative), Euphemia (use of good words),
  Euphanta (pleasant), Eusynallaxia (fairness),
  Euschemata (well-formed), Euxinia (hospitable), Eucharia (grace),
  Euchrestia (easily used), Euzygia (well-matched)
- Purely imaginary names:

  Aclemaareymia Aglonsonytte Alliareidaanyette Antteychiny
  *Apchire* *Aspoja* Atteraree Ballutte Bliilassia *Bofmemia*
  Bretteroxure Casraelamiiwatte Chejossy Chewantteany Chobrorea
  Chonootte Chreemaitte Chrylere Clutinytte Creacossy Creevumia
  Daareal Dalaorrea *Dascolylore* Debeal Dejeal Deraria *Discha*
  *Donquony* Dreedinytte *Dreonpiny* Duploabony Eclepriiffia
  *Ejucmaire* Eluginy Equodure Erretteaberee Evoquiny Fachunytte
  Fejenytte Feveudutte *Flasmaenea* Flettekaennya Folenytte
  Freanuny Gajegotte Gareyttenuny *Gesmemia* *Giipreufdea* Gloenyny
  Goblex Gudiareony Hychere Hynnyare Hyphleny Idreechenytte Ifrial
  *Isquany* Ivevirosore Jantesnyette Jarraodotte Jemiafureossy
  Joareossy Jujevanye Kegujumaare Kiipnyutte Lajovuthiereenytte
  Lepliechire Lessarrua Lintanytte Lissaffany Lonyquoblaolae
  Lotteudaureomia Majonytte Maslevotte Melemaire Mestteaclossy
  Modreamaunenytte Molinytte *Naaphsy* Namasemia Nataazatte
  *Nedocnyny* Neslae Nidreyny Niiruowissia Nijassumia Nollemia
  Noslijeny Nullasse Nureenytte Nytreottee Oflubatte Omiapeeplee
  Opnenytte Otteheddoa Ovenytitte Pecreiny Peonuny Pidrunyare
  Piittereissia Pliivassia Pojaquenytte Prasreolassia Preenyymia
  Qiobumia Quajare Quelomia Quettii Racche Rakittee Rasraal
  Razedany Ressie Rhachyny Richralure Ridreivua Risttiimaare
  Rochareuddotte Rommaare *Ropsore* Runyquissia Rutinytte Saslitte
  Segiilore Siliisa Sladavore Sluvettereemia Sodureitte
  *Srecpareuny* Sreiscossy Talaedere Tanytteamia Tegabboal Telial
  Tetteonyajare Thagore Thebyre Thepax Thiittehial Thipuny
  Tiettenejunyumia *Tiickerey* Tipzenytte Tobreottehamia Totteare
  Treasiny Triechare Truiloa *Ujavefduny* *Umiabapnue* Utterievual
  Vaffussy Vechonytte *Vefnasalany* Vereenytte Vezeamaele
  *Vijacfofraere* Vocumiabie Waddette Wavumauny Zachumia Zanycheda
  Ziittenyare Zottehuny Zriipomia